Can We Use Google API Classes (TextRun, ParagraphElement, StructuralElement, etc.) to Construct an Object and Post Using Request/Batch Update?
Using Google API with Java for Google Docs, we can access classes like TextRun, ParagraphElement, etc. and set the values, for example, as follows:
TextRun txtRun = new TextRun();
txtRun.setContent("EXAMPLE STRING");
ParagraphElement pElem = new ParagraphElement();
pElem.setTextRun(txtRun1);


However, it's not clear how to add the above created object to the Request Class and then post using BatchUpdate. Ideally, we can construct the document as in the above code then add it to a request with something like:
Request req = new Request();
req.setParagraphElement(pElem);
BatchUpdate...setRequests(req);

We are able to modify a Google Doc using the classes/methods available to the Request class.

I have the same problem.  When creating a Request from the Google Docs API, below are some of the options to set or update the request.

set(java.lang.String fieldName, java.lang.Object value)
setCreateFooter(CreateFooterRequest createFooter)
setCreateFootnote(CreateFootnoteRequest createFootnote)
setCreateHeader(CreateHeaderRequest createHeader)
setCreateParagraphBullets(CreateParagraphBulletsRequest
createParagraphBullets) setInsertInlineImage(InsertInlineImageRequest
insertInlineImage) setInsertPageBreak(InsertPageBreakRequest
insertPageBreak) setInsertSectionBreak(InsertSectionBreakRequest
insertSectionBreak) setInsertTable(InsertTableRequest insertTable)
setInsertText(InsertTextRequest insertText)
setUpdateDocumentStyle(UpdateDocumentStyleRequest updateDocumentStyle)
setUpdateParagraphStyle(UpdateParagraphStyleRequest
updateParagraphStyle) setUpdateSectionStyle(UpdateSectionStyleRequest
updateSectionStyle) setUpdateTableRowStyle(UpdateTableRowStyleRequest
updateTableRowStyle) setUpdateTextStyle(UpdateTextStyleRequest
updateTextStyle)

I can successfully insert text using setInsertText() or create a table using setInsertTable(), or update styling of an existing paragraph using setUpdateTextStyle().  But, I cannot build a paragraph with styling and then add it to the document.  None of the above methods seem to allow this.  I’ve tried in two ways, first:
// get document obj
String strDocId = "aaaa";
Docs docsObj = GDriveConnection.getDocsObj();
Document documentObj = docsObj.documents().get(strDocId).execute();


// generate a paragraph
Paragraph paraObj = new Paragraph();

TextStyle textStyleObj = new TextStyle();
textStyleObj.setBold(true);
TextRun textRunObj1 = new TextRun();
textRunObj1.setContent(“Hello paragraph 1");
textRunObj1.setTextStyle(textStyleObj);
ParagraphElement paraElemObj1 = new ParagraphElement();
paraElemObj1.setTextRun(textRunObj1);
            
TextRun textRunObj2 = new TextRun();
textRunObj2.setContent(“Hello paragraph 2”);
ParagraphElement paraElemObj2 = new ParagraphElement();
paraElemObj2.setTextRun(textRunObj2);

ArrayList<ParagraphElement> aryLParaElemObjs = new ArrayList<ParagraphElement>();
aryLParaElemObjs.add(paraElemObj1);
aryLParaElemObjs.add(paraElemObj2);
paraObj.setElements(aryLParaElemObjs);

// set structural obj and add to array          
StructuralElement structuralElementObj = new StructuralElement();
structuralElementObj.setParagraph(paraObj);

ArrayList<StructuralElement> aryLStructuralElementObj = new ArrayList<StructuralElement>();
aryLStructuralElementObj.add(structuralElementObj);

// add structural elem array to body
Body bodyObj = new Body();
bodyObj.setContent(aryLStructuralElementObj);

// batch update
BatchUpdateDocumentRequest batchUpdateDocReqObj = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest().set("body", bodyObj);
BatchUpdateDocumentResponse batchUpdateDocResponseObj = docsObj.documents().batchUpdate(strDocId, batchUpdateDocReqObj).execute();


documentObj.setBody(bodyObj);

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest batchUpdateDocReqObj = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest().set("body", bodyObj);
docsObj.documents().batchUpdate(strDocId, batchUpdateDocReqObj).execute();

The second way was instead of using batchUpdate(), I tried using the docsObj.documents().create(), but this was also unsuccessful.
I've tried many many different things including the above, but none are working.
How can I piece by piece generate a paragraph object with text runs and styling and then update this or set it to a Google Document?  None of the existing methods seem to do this.  This is very easy to do for a Word doc using docx4j, but just a simple task like this is not simple to do with the Google API.  Thank you
